# How to add multiple songs in Apple music to a playlist?

Tags: itunes, macos, apple-music

I'm using Itunes 12.8.0.150 on macOS Sierra. When I browse certain album on Apple music I want to add multiple songs of that album to my playlist. I tried pressing Shift or CMD to select multiple songs but this just doesn't work. Do you know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It does select all songs in an album by pressing CMD. I'm on 10.13.3 High Sierra. Try it again. If it doesn't work send a screenshot or screen record if you can.